# Lisp - Remove instances of a list of pairs from another list of pairs

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to write a function in lisp that takes two lists of pairs and removes all occurrences of the first list from the second list. 
As an example, if we have `list1 ((a b)(cd))` and `list2 ((g h)(a b)(j i))`, by calling this function the result would be `((g h)(j i))`.

Until now i have the following code (which is not working):

```
(defun retira(obj l1)
  (cond ((null l1) ())
        ((equal obj (first l1)) (retira obj (rest l1)))
        (t (cons (first l1) (retira obj (rest l1))))))

(defun retira-ocupadas (tabuleiro lista-adj)
  (if (equal (first (todos-ocupados tabuleiro)) (first lista-adj))
    (retira (car (todos-ocupados tabuleiro)) lista-adj))

  (retira-ocupadas (rest (todos-ocupados tabuleiro)) (rest lista-adj)))
```

Where `retira` should remove all occurrences of an object in a list and `retira-ocupadas` should take care of comparing, if the object from the first list is equal to an object from the second list. `Todos-ocupados` is a function that generates the first list.

This is currently not working, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: oh sorry, todos-ocupados is a function that generates the first list.

Comment: But retire-ocupadas passes the RESULTS of calling todos-ocupados, and then applies T-O to that result w/ every recursive call.

Comment: You're right, i should use a variable where i store the result from todos-ocupados. This way i'm using the right results with the recursive call. thx

Comment: Could you be more specific about how its behavior differs from what is desired?

Comment: Is that some homework ? Anyway, you should look at `remove-if` and `member`. However you should use english in your code especially when you paste it on an international website.

Comment: It's not homework, it was a school project i already delivered, now i'm just trying to make it better as a personal project. I get no results at all, i think i get an infinite cycle of some kind.

Comment: @CláudioRibeiro: CL has a lot of functions to manipulate lists, you should use them instead of rolling your own (unless you really want to implement them). Also I say it again, play a bit with `remove-if` and `member`. (hint: the default `:test` function might not do what you want but you can change it)

Comment: Thanks Daimrod i will be looking at remove-if and member functions ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to remove any element of the second list that is a member of the first.

```
(defun remove-list (list-to-remove target-list)
  (remove-if (lambda (element)
               (member element list-to-remove
                       :test #'equal))
             target-list))
```

Please note the definition of `equal`, perhaps you want `equalp` instead (or perhaps you need to write your own `pair-equal`).

Comment: [Here](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/PS/EQUAL.html) is a good text which explains why equality isn't simple, and why there is so many function to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun list-difference (list1 list2 &key (test #'eql))
  (loop for item in list1
        unless (member item list2 :test test)
        collect item))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER > (list-difference '((g h) (a b) (j i))
                           '((a b) (cd))
                           :test #'equal)
((G H) (J I))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
(defun multi-remove (a b)
  (loop for e in b
        do (setf a (remove e a)))
```

This goes through every element of b and destructively removes all occurrences of it in a.

Comment: Or for a non-destructive (and more functional-style) option: `(defun multiRemove (a b) (car (last (mapcar #'(lambda (e) (setf a (remove e a))) b ))))`

Comment: Well, no.  In your answer, the variable `a` inside the function is modified, but Lisp is pass-by-value.  In your comment, you need to give a different `:test` argument to `remove` to make it work, and that is a rather convoluted use of `mapcar` (there are many other "looping" constructs that fit better here).

Comment: Oh, and you exchanged the meaning of the two arguments, compared to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`set-difference` will do this but will not necessarily preserve the order of the lists:

```
? (let ((list1 '((a b) (c d)))
        (list2 '((g h) (a b) (j i))))
    (set-difference list2 list1 :test 'equal))
((J I) (G H))
```